# Optimize Images for Google Page Speed

Tags: image-processing, google-pagespeed, mod-pagespeed, image-optimization

i'm tryng to optimize the images from my webpage to fit the google pagespeed test. But i didnt get how to compress the files with the tools provided by google on the size that google wants to have.

So i use jpegoptim and jpegtran for jpegs with this command:
jpegoptim.exe FILENAME
jpegtran.exe -copy none -debug -optimize -copy none -outfile FILENAME FILENAME

Where FILENAME is the fullpath to the img file. In most cases the files would be a bit smaller, but not that small if i download it from google(over the PageSpeed Insights Tool). Can anyone help me to find out the right parameters or another tool(working on windows) that gives me perfect results(or results that are accepted by Google).

THanks in advance,
J. Doe ;)

Comment: Try adding --strip-all to your current command?

Comment: Thats exactly what google is recommending. But its still giving me an error about image optimization...

Comment: Google Page Speed has changed their algorithm by mid of December, 2016. To fulfill the new requirements you have to use a lossy optimization. A good source for more details about this can be found here (statements by Joshua Marantz, Google): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!profile/pagespeed-insights-discuss/APn2wQeG85ig7-3gpHenmtFyqlANacCV7tioZ94BWFCBjqZS4LBP0FZI7lDTvnI2flED5wOT6WeB/pagespeed-insights-discuss/T76MeBILCks/35WVHIDCDgAJ

Comment: I'm not seeing details about updated algorithm for image, care to give more details?

Answer (score 0):

In the end of the Google page speed insights page is a link where you can download optimized resources for your website.
Link is called:
**Download optimized image, JavaScript, and CSS resources for this page.**